# MySQL TITLE QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Ok, so very new to SQL, but im starting to learn…but I have a question and im sure its simple. i have a database i'm working on and the question asks me to find the "title" of a courses prereq, so, the class is english 201, and its prereq is english 101. i have to write the query so that the result is the title and ID of english 101. so far this is, below, what i have, but the title is the part i can't figure out. I know its a simply question, but i am quite new and just learning!

when i run this code, i get the title and info for 'cs-315' im just a bit confused on how to get it to get the stuff i want, i feel like i need a subquery...

```
select title, course_id,prereq_id 
from prereq natural join course
where course_id='cs-315'
```

Comment: **TIPS** Be neat with your SQL statements, Capitalize keywords like SELECT, WHERE, AND, FROM, etc.

Comment: you're right, ill do better in the future! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NATURAL JOIN` joins the tables on all the columns that have the same name. But you want to find the rows in `course` that match the prerequisite in `prereq`, not match `course_id` directly between them, so you need an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT c.title, p.course_id, p.prereq_id
FROM prereq AS p
INNER JOIN course AS c ON c.course_id = p.prereq_id
WHERE p.course_id = 'cs-315'
```

Comment: thank you so much! I just finished reading about joins, so its still a little unfamiliar!

Comment: also, since you are here, why did you add "c." "p."? what does that do?

Comment: Those are table aliases, so you don't have to write out the full table name every time you refer to a table.

Comment: E.g. `c.course_id` is short for `course.course_id`. If two tables have columns with the same name, you need to specify which table you're referring to.

Comment: OHH, ok, yeah the part about "course.course_id" i knew for when you had two tables with the same name, but making it shorter by adding the     "." i was not aware of! thanks! and the code worked like a charm!